# IF statement for iMacros Frame knowing the range

Tags: if-statement, macros, scripting, frame, imacros

I'm doing a macro but Frame number change, I know that this topic already exist but, I know the range of the frame, 5,6,7,8.

I want to make an IF else else else.
This is all my macros code, with FRAME F=5.

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Entra<SP>y<SP>juega
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:nueva
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=ID:new_user ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Nombre<SP>de<SP>usuario
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','w','x','y','z']; var string = ''; for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){string += letters[parseInt(Math.random() * 25)]}; string")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:new_user ATTR=ID:user_username CONTENT={{!var1}}
TAB T=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:pubinboxfield
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:inboxfield CONTENT={{!var1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BTN ATTR=TXT:Go!
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=ID:new_user ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Email
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:new_user ATTR=ID:user_email CONTENT={{!var1}}@
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:new_user ATTR=ID:user_password CONTENT=BANrCXf2bkM4uvxeSORkLxUpmItcz9Lusq6IaZQ3mL3yozehFkMJnfz3msgD+NnA7mBkCwAvPI+90ieW3VOGzg==
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:new_user ATTR=ID:user_password_confirmation CONTENT=K1rNDyUqpAtDiYrdjh+43msyM72lnYWGL3rdB2lQecy+4UBQQ1F51qOPP9xFRv6/3y78xQyWtkd+4qa3II5wNg==
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:new_user ATTR=ID:terms_and_conditions CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:new_user ATTR=NAME:commit
TAB T=2
WAIT SECONDS=60
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Bienvenido<SP>Confirma<SP>tu<SP>cuenta
FRAME F=5 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Empieza<SP>a<SP>jugar*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Fútbol
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Liga
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Juega
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=ID:bet_form_71595 ATTR=ID:label_option_id_479188
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:bet_form_71595 ATTR=ID:option_id_479188
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:NUMBER FORM=ID:bet_form_71595 ATTR=ID:points CONTENT=500
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:bet_form_71595 ATTR=ID:play-action
WAIT SECONDS=20
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:×
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Liga
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Juega
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=ID:bet_form_71601 ATTR=ID:label_option_id_479262
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:bet_form_71601 ATTR=ID:option_id_479262
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:NUMBER FORM=ID:bet_form_71601 ATTR=ID:points CONTENT=500
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:bet_form_71601 ATTR=ID:play-action
WAIT SECONDS=20
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Liga
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Juega
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=ID:bet_form_71490 ATTR=ID:label_option_id_478013
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:bet_form_71490 ATTR=ID:option_id_478013
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:NUMBER FORM=ID:bet_form_71490 ATTR=ID:points CONTENT=3000
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:bet_form_71490 ATTR=ID:play-action
WAIT SECONDS=20
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:fa<SP>fa-sign-out&&TXT:
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.exampleweb1.com/
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=https://www.exampleweb2.com/
```

Thanks for all, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var macro;

    macro = "CODE:" + "\n";
    macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n";
    macro += "FRAME F={{frame}}" + "\n";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Juega* CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER" + "\n";


    var macro1;

    macro1 = "CODE:" + "\n";
    macro1 += "FRAME F={{frame}}" + "\n";
    macro1 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Juega* " + "\n";
    macro1 += "TAB T=2" + "\n";

    //declare frame
    var frame = 1;

    //loop until script finds matching frame
    while (true) {
        iimSet("frame", frame)
        ret = iimPlay(macro)

        //if macro returns true then frame has been found. break and play macro1
        if (ret > 0) {
            break;
        }

        frame++;
    }

    //set the frame and play macro
    iimSet("frame", frame)
     iimPlay(macro1)
```

This should be the code you are looking for. Test it and see if it works.

Comment: Hello, I edit my post, I put all my macro because i can´t implement your code, let you see, and thanks for all.

Comment: This is too long for me to make you a macro. But you have an example. Wrap the iMacros code with javascript code and execute it . The process is almost the same you just have more coding.

Comment: Is it possible to combine macro code with javascript, or have to do everything to javascript?  I know java, c++ and c but no javascript, thanks.

Comment: JavaScript is similar to java. I've written the combination of iMacros and JavaScript. From this example try to figure out the rest of the code.

Comment: Split the main macro into multiple macros. When the webpage comes that has frames on it then activate searching for frame.

Comment: I'm try to do that but your code doesn't work. "BadParameter: Unsupported variable !TIMEOUT_STEO, line 2 (Error code: -911)"

Comment: chane it now to SET !TIMEOUT_STEP